# Android: SpeechRecognizer beep

Tags: android, speech-recognition, beep

Ok in Jelly Bean SpeecRecognizer have beep sound... I want to have same sound (or sound i choose) in the older versions.

I am doing it like this at the moment

```
                int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
                        //prepare beep
                    beep.start();
                }
                //prepare intent
                sr.startListening(intent);
```

But there is still time between beep and listening... where in the SpeechRecognizer listener i need to put this beep start if below jb ?

I want to tell that i don't want to play the beep sound while recording, because it will mess my recognition!

And also if someone can find me the beep sound drom JB will be great :)

Answer (score 0):

You can place it in onReadyForSpeech (if you implement RecogntionListener)

```
    public class MySpeechRecognizer implements RecognitionListener {
            public void initialize()
            {
                //... other SpeechRecognizer initialization
                mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);
            }
            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
                final ToneGenerator tg = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
                tg.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP);
           }
           //... other required methods of RecognitionListener
    }
```

The only problem with this is that the beep will cause for recognition to start, so you'll need to restart recognition in the event that you get an error 7(no results) in onError.

Alternatively, I've gone with the solution of vibrating (except for when using a bluetooth headset) instead of beeping because vibrating won't get detected by the speech recognition.

```
@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
    Log.d("SpeechRecognizer", "Ready");
    if (beepOnReady && !hasBeeped) {
        Log.d("SpeechRecognizer", "Beeping");
        hasBeeped = true;
        if (beepOnBluetooth) {
            final ToneGenerator tg = new ToneGenerator(6, 100);
            tg.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP);
        }
        else
        {
            Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) ;
            vibe.vibrate(50);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But `onReadyForSpeech` is not the place also vibration is not what I need... my way is better than onReadyForSpeech.....
I saied above that I don't want to run the beep while recording... and onReadyForSpeech is recording time!

Comment: Yes, sadly I've done a lot of research into this for my own app http://Carma.RSenApps.com , I've found that the vibration solution was the best possible, please let me know if anything changes though :)

Comment: Ok I will let you know... Until end of July we will start refreshing our application so I have some things on my mind and we will try them.... if they work I will let you know :p